# How to Carrying some values of PHP Session

Tags: php

I want to send some values with php sessions through the current page(eg.php) to another page(a.php). But i cannot make it because some error. just like

"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\eg.php:6) in C:\xampp\htdocs\eg.php on line 14"

How to resolve it?

### My eg.php code

```
session_start();
define("Username",$name);
define("Password",$password);
$_SESSION['user'] = $name;
echo "<form action =\"\" method = \"post\">";
echo "<input type =\"text\" placeholder =\"Username\" name = \"user\">";
echo "<input type =\"password\" placeholder = \"password\" name = \"pass\">";
echo "<input type =\"submit\" value =\"name\" name = \"btn\">";
echo "</form>";
if(isset($_POST['user']) === true && isset($_POST['pass']) === true){
    $_SESSION['user'] == Username;
    session_write_close();
    header("location:a.php");
}
```

### My a.php code

```
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: put `ob_Start()` on the first line of your code. after the opening tag of `<?php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Make this changes

**in eg.php**
at first line in php code do this

```
ob_start();
```

at end/last line in php code do this

```
ob_end_flush();
```

**in a.php code**

at first line use

```
session_start();
```

It will work.

Comment: I already do it. It's not working. Say another way.Thanks you help

Comment: For me its working try to change your php version and try.